# Why does Dart's Set data type have .first and .last properties if Sets are unordered?

Tags: dart, set

I'm confused about the Set data type in `Dart`. According to the documentation, Sets are unordered, meaning that the order in which items are added to the Set is not preserved. However, I noticed that Sets in `Dart` have a .first property and a .last property. How is this possible if Sets are unordered? Can someone explain why these properties exist and how to use them effectively?

Comment: Because `Set` implements the `Iterable` interface which have those properties. So what you get is basically the first/last element in case you would do a iteration over the `Set`. And yes, you should not trust the order of the `Set` (well, basically the default `Set` used in Dart is `LinkedHashSet` which keeps the insertion order. But it is a good rule of thumb to not see `Set` as something in any specific order.)

Answer (score 4):

Dart offers three `Set` implementations in its standard library: `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet` (the default), and `SplayTreeSet`. All three implement the `Set` interface, which means they must all implement `Iterable`.

`SplayTreeSet` and `LinkedHashSet` both have specified iteration orders. `HashSet` does not, but still implements `Iterable`. The [API documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-collection/HashSet-class.html) of `HashSet` has the following to say on the matter:

> The iteration order of the set is not specified and depends on the hashcodes of the provided elements. However, the order is stable: multiple iterations over the same set produce the same order, as long as the set is not modified.

So while it's not often very useful to depend on the order of items in a `HashSet`, you can, so long as it is not modified.

In general, while some `Set` implementations are not ordered, it makes sense for them to be `Iterable`, so that they can be used with other non-ordered `Iterable` APIs such as for loops or [`Iterable.any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-core/Iterable/any.html). There is a lot you can do with `Iterable`s that does not relate to the order of elements.